# Finding the sum of series help: $\displaystyle\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} (-9)^nx^n. $

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, closed-form

I have a question that I am kind of stuck on. I am good with series stuff, but this one kind of threw me off

$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} (-9)^nx^n. $$

This is the question and I was supposed to find out the values of where $x$ converges, and I found that out to be from $-\frac{1}{9} < x < \frac{1}{9}$

How can I find the sum of the series for those values of $x$?

Comment: This is the infinite geometric series $\sum_1^\infty (-9x)^n$. You have probably known this sum for a long time.

Comment: yeah but how do i find the sum for those values of x. its not infinty for some reason

Comment: When $|r|\lt 1$, $a+ar+ar^2+\cdots =\frac{a}{1-r}$. In our case $a=-9x$, $r=-9x$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given the closed form of the geometric series:
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty a^n = \frac{a}{1-a}
$$

Plug $a = -9x$ to get:
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-9)^nx^n = \frac{-9x}{1+9x}
$$

Comment: i dont get it, so is the sum 0?

Comment: @MathGeek The sum depends on $x$. For example if $x = 1/18$ then the sum is $-1/3$.

Comment: but i know my series only converges from -1/9 to 1/9 is my x  1/9 then ? :s

Comment: @MathGeek $x$ can take any value in $(-1/9, 1/9)$. The sum is a function of $x$. You cannot give a fixed number as the sum for all values of $x$.

Comment: if i integrate from -1/9 to 1/9 i get it does not exist :s

Answer (score 3):

To compute the interval of convergence for a power series $\sum a^n x^n$, compute $$\lim_{n\to \infty} \sqrt[\large n]{|a_n|} = \lim_{n\to\infty} \sqrt[\large n]{9^n}$$

In this case, that gives us $9$, so the *radius* of convergence is $\dfrac {1}9$ which will converge when $|x| \lt \dfrac 19$

Comment: yes i understand that i got the answer that it only converges from x betweeen -1/9 t0 1/9 but i dont get the next question "Find the sum of the series for those values of x"

Comment: I think you mean the interval of convergence is $|x|<1/9$.

Comment: but how do i find the sum of the series now thats my main question. i know how to get the interval of convergence

Comment: Perhaps you need to take twice the integral from $0$ to $1/9$ of $$\frac{-9x}{1 + 9x}$$, which is $\dfrac 29 (\ln(2) - 1)$

Answer (score 0):

It can be written as $(-9x)^n$ so the ratio here is $-9x$. Since it starts at $1$ so the first term is $-9x$ and that is also the ratio, so $\frac{-9x}{1+9x}$ because you use the formula (1st term)/(1-ratio) so $x$ will still have to be in your answer.